# Creating a Factory association that defaults to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, factories

Using the FactoryGirl gem, inside the factories.rb file, how can I create a factory with an association that defaults to nil?

I am thinking something along these lines:

```
Factory.define :user do |factory|
  factory.association :post
  factory.association :comment, :default => nil
end
```

Would that be right and would that be ok to do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `nil` by default if you do not mention this association in your factory definition at all?

Comment: Good point.  I was worried that doing that would mean using Factory in the seeds.rb file wouldn't work, but I believe now that worrying was incorrect.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20407116/474597 if you want to override association to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Factory.define :user do |factory|
  factory.association :post
  factory.comment_id  nil
end
```

Answer (score 11):

FactoryGirl now benefits from a [`:null` strategy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v5.0.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy/null.rb). Therefore, you can define your association like this:

```
factory :user do
  association :post
  association :comment, strategy: :null
end
```

This will leave the association set to `nil` when using this factory. It's better to use this strategy than not defining the association altogether, because you can easily change strategies in traits/in the future.

Comment: gosh, it'd be nice if FactoryBot would mention this in their docs, no?