# Disabling a FactoryGirl association within a trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot, traits

In a Rails app, I'm using FactoryGirl to define a general factory plus several more specific traits. The general case and all but one of the traits have a particular association, but I'd like to define a trait where that association is not created/built. I can use an `after` callback to set the association's `id` to `nil`, but this doesn't stop the association record from being created in the first place.

Is there a way in a trait definition to completely disable the creation/building of an association that has been defined for the factory the trait belongs to?

For example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    attribute "value"
    association :bar

    trait :one do
      # This has the bar association
    end

    trait :two do
      association :bar, turn_off_somehow: true
      # foos created with trait :two will have bar_id = nil
      # and an associated bar will never be created
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand this correctly. Are you saying that you want to prohibit Rails from calling callbacks that create other associated model instances when you create a model instance when you are using FactoryGirl to create that model instance??

Comment: @dmtri.com: I added an example, does that help explain what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An association in factory_girl is just an attribute like any other. Using `association :bar` sets the `bar` attribute, so you can disable it by overriding it with `nil`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    attribute "value"
    association :bar

    trait :one do
      # This has the bar association
    end

    trait :two do
      bar nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Joe Ferris' answer but appears it does not work anymore in factory_bot 5.0.0. I found this  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437936/creating-a-factory-association-that-defaults-to-nil/34836827#34836827) that referred to the `strategy: :null` flag that can be passed to the association like:

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    attribute "value"
    association :bar

    trait :one do
      # This has the bar association
    end

    trait :two do
      association :bar, strategy: :null
    end
  end
end
```

It seems to do the trick now.

[Source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v5.0.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy/null.rb) looks like it just stops any callbacks like create or build so renders the association to nothing.

```rb
module FactoryBot
  module Strategy
    class Null
      def association(runner); end

      def result(evaluation); end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe you can also just do `bar { nil }` if the association allows it re: validations